# Passing a string parameter with many commas in SQL through Excel ADO

Tags: sql, excel, stored-procedures, parameters, vba

I would like to execute stored procedure through Excel ADO. Is there any way to pass parameter with many commas?

In VBA I have:

```
par1="'1','2','3'"
par2="'somthing else'"

EXEC MyProcedure par1, par2
```

It cannot be done that way because SQL reads it as four parameters (not two):

```
EXEC MyProcedure '1','2','3','somthing else'
```

What I am doing now is to change commas in par1 to any sets of characters which will become delimiter i.e. `@@@` and then send it as a one string:

```
par1="'1@@@2@@@3'"
```

Then I can use:

```
EXEC MyProcedure par1, par2
```

Then in SQL I regain the original delimiter with

```
par1=REPLACE(par1,'@@@',',')
```

Is there any other simpler way which allows to keep commas in par1? Something like:

```
EXEC MyProcedure par1='1','2','3', par2='somthing else'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 2x single quotes to include them in the string... `'''1'',''2'',''3'',''Something Else'''`

A breakdown:

```
' -- Opens a string
'' -- a single quote in a string
''' -- opens a string and places a single quote inside it
```

Comment: What is the logic behind 2x single quotes? Is each element wrapped or is each comma wrapped with 2x single quote? Do I need to wrap all the parameters with single quote or one would be enough I mean `'''1'',''2'',''3''','Something Else'`

Comment: Thanks. Just my second question please. Do I need to wrap all the parameters with single quote or one would be enough I mean `'''1'',''2'',''3''','Something Else'`

Comment: If `Something Else` is not part of the same string, then a single quote (as per your comment) will do